# Is the NuGetToolInstaller task supposed to require .Net 4.7.2 and should using the task add .Net framework 4.7.2 as a demand?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a build VM that's on an older version of Windows 10 because we have a 3rd party component that can't be installed on newer versions. That version of Windows 10 doesn't support installing .Net Framework 4.7.2, and this appears to be required for the NuGetToolInstaller to work. Is there anyway to get NuGet working in a build that will work with all Windows 10 builds (or even Windows 7)?

I can force it to only choose to build on a VM with a later build of Windows 10 by manually adding a demand for .Net Framework 4.7.2, but shouldn't the NuGetToolInstaller task already include that demand (in the same way that the Visual Studio Build task does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and this appears to be required for the NuGetToolInstaller to work.

Check this [json file](https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json), it shows all the supported versions in task `NuGettoolinstaller`, we can see that it can be installed from version `2.8.6`, I try to install it with the version `2.8.6` and it works, check the pic below.

[image]

According to the description, it seems that you are using self-hosted agent, it will check the configuration of the local machine. If you have another version installed on your local agent machine, we can also use the NuGet version.